# ANDROID - Orientation changes

Tags: android, orientation, landscape, portrait

I am actually having the following problem : I can not enter in the method `onConfigurationChanged` when I change the orientation of the emulator.

This is my method :

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
 // Checks the orientation of the screen
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        Log.i("ORIENTATION", "CHANGED TO LANDSCAPE");



    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        Log.i("ORIENTATION", "CHANGED TO PORTRAIT");
    }
}
```

I do not have any log when i change the orientation ..

I have read that a modification happened from the older version about the manifest, the older verstion was :

```
**android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"**
```

And the new one is :

```
**android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"**
```

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.fruitsapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.fruitsapp.MenuFruitsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity 
             android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:name=".DescriptionFruitActivity"
             android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|screenSize">
         </activity>

    </application>



</manifest>
```

Unfortunatly, after loads of tries, I still not have Log to signal that my orientation changed ..

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.....

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

Hope this helps.